# Create table in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am new to DB2. I tried creating a table with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.CERTIFICATE_TAB
(
    CERT_ID                     CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR            SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
    EFFECTIVE_DT                DATE NOT NULL,
    CERT_EFF_TYPE_CD            CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CERT_STATUS_CD              CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CERT_VER_NBR                SMALLINT(5),
    EXPIRATION_DT               DATE NOT NULL,
    CERT_NBR                    INTEGER(10),
    CERT_ISSUE_CD               CHAR(1),
    CERT_DTB_CD                 CHAR(1),
    CERT_ERROR_CD               CHAR(10),
    FORM_AS_OF_DT               DATE,
    CERT_RNL_STATUS_CD          CHAR(1),
    CERT_CTU_CNC_IND            CHAR(1),
    CERT_FLD_ISS_IND            CHAR(1),
    CERT_MANUAL_IND             CHAR(1),
    CERT_FLD_ISS_BY_CD          CHAR(1),
    MNL_ADDENDUM_IND            CHAR(1),
    FORM_LEVEL1_CD              CHAR(10),
    FORM_LEVEL2_CD              CHAR(10),
    DOC_ON_FILE_IND             CHAR(1),
    STD_POL_IND                 CHAR(1),
    WET_SIGN_IND                CHAR(1),
    CERT_USER_ID                CHAR(25),
    CERT_ROUTE_PATH_CD          CHAR(10),
    CERT_USER_TXT               VARCHAR(255),
    CERT_ERROR_DES              VARCHAR(2000),
    LAST_MDF_USER_ID            CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ISSUE_ACY_TS                TIMESTAMP(26,6),
    LAST_MDF_ACY_TS             TIMESTAMP(26,6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SQL120103120640250 PRIMARY KEY (CERT_ID, CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR),
    CONSTRAINT CMSICER1 UNIQUE (CERT_ID, CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR)
);
```

However I got the below error

Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=SMALLINT;CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR;CHARACTER, DRIVER=3.50.152
 SQLState:  42601
 ErrorCode: -104

Could someone plz point out what mistake am I doin?

Comment: You can find out the correct syntax yourself by reading the manual: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F2-9-7-101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the all the extra size specifiers you don't specify the size of a SMALLINT, INTEGER or TIMESTAMP.  Also use CHARACTER not CHAR

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.CERTIFICATE_TAB
(
    CERT_ID                     CHARACTER(36) NOT NULL,
    CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR            SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    EFFECTIVE_DT                DATE NOT NULL,
    CERT_EFF_TYPE_CD            CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
    CERT_STATUS_CD              CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL,
    CERT_VER_NBR                SMALLINT,
    EXPIRATION_DT               DATE NOT NULL,
   CERT_NBR                    INTEGER,
    CERT_ISSUE_CD               CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_DTB_CD                 CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_ERROR_CD               CHARACTER(10),
    FORM_AS_OF_DT               DATE,
    CERT_RNL_STATUS_CD          CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_CTU_CNC_IND            CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_FLD_ISS_IND            CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_MANUAL_IND             CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_FLD_ISS_BY_CD          CHARACTER(1),
    MNL_ADDENDUM_IND            CHARACTER(1),
    FORM_LEVEL1_CD              CHARACTER(10),
    FORM_LEVEL2_CD              CHARACTER(10),
    DOC_ON_FILE_IND             CHARACTER(1),
    STD_POL_IND                 CHARACTER(1),
    WET_SIGN_IND                CHARACTER(1),
    CERT_USER_ID                CHARACTER(25),
    CERT_ROUTE_PATH_CD          CHARACTER(10),
    CERT_USER_TXT               VARCHAR(255),
    CERT_ERROR_DES              VARCHAR(2000),
    LAST_MDF_USER_ID            CHARACTER(25) NOT NULL,
    ISSUE_ACY_TS                TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_MDF_ACY_TS             TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SQL120103120640250 PRIMARY KEY (CERT_ID, CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR),
    CONSTRAINT CMSICER1 UNIQUE (CERT_ID, CERT_TRS_SEQ_NBR)
);
```